# Complicated query involving res

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the table as below and I need to have the query how many tasks  created for the day and how many are resolved and I need to capture the Tasks which are passed from previous day with active status. Ex: TaskId 101 is created on 11/10/2014 and it is resolved on 11/12/2014 so  it should show in the count of 11/11/2014 and 11/12/2014 also.

```
TaskId CreateDate Status ResolvedDate
101 11/10/2014 Resolved 11/12/2014
102 11/10/2014 Resolved 11/10/2014
103 11/11/2014 Active NULL 
104 11/11/2014 Resolved 11/13/2014
105 11/13/2014 Active 11/13/2014
```

Please help me as I am not able to think of any solution. Sorry I was trying to post the table schema in table format but not able to create table and I am new to this forum.

Comment: what have you tried?  seems like a simple case statement looking at create and resolved date should do it.

Comment: If you're really about to lose your job you should put a little more effort on your question. I can't help you if I can't understand you

Comment: Show some sample data and a few more sample results. This will help you get your answer faster.

Comment: "for the day" what day? just today (date of run)? or for each date in the table? for every day in the year? again, not sure what the expected result should be...

Comment: why not just add a column that shows how long it took from created to resolved?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the result using `case based aggregation`

The CTE generates list of dates for a given range.

For each day, total active ( created that day and created previously but not resolved) and total resolved that day are calculated using `case`, `max` and `group by`

```
declare @start_date datetime = '2014-11-10'
declare @end_date datetime ='2014-11-13'


;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @start_date AS date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, date) as date
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, date) <= @end_date
)
select cte.date,
       sum( case when  createDate <= cte.date and ( resolveddate is null or  ResolvedDate >= cte.date) then 1 else 0 end
          ) as TotalActive,

       sum( case when cte.date = ResolvedDate then 1 else 0 end
          ) as TotalResolved
from cte
left join Table1 T
ON T.createDate <= cte.date
GROUP BY CTE.DATE
```

Comment: Radar - The query giving zero count for both columns (Totalactive, TotalResolved)....

Comment: @SayaramGattu, i am giving start date as 1st Nov, look at 10th, 11th date, also you can change start date to 10th Nov, if you don't  it from nov 1st. look here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fddbe9/6

Comment: @SayaramGattu, try now NULL condition for resolveddate handled.

Answer (score 0):

@radar, You just gave me the hope with the query and I have changed the query as below and it started showing result. But the TotalActive showing less value than TotalCreated.

```
declare @start_date datetime = getdate()-30
declare @end_date datetime = getdate()
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @start_date AS date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, date) as date
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, date) <= @end_date
)
select cte.date,
        sum( case when CONVERT(varchar, CreateDate, 101) <= CONVERT(varchar, cte.date, 101) and CONVERT(varchar, cte.date, 101) <= CONVERT(varchar, ResolveDate, 101) then 1 else 0 end
          ) as TotalActive,
          sum( case when  CONVERT(varchar, cte.date, 101) = CONVERT(varchar, CreateDate, 101) then 1 else 0 end
          ) as TotalCreated,
       sum( case when CONVERT(varchar, cte.date, 101) = CONVERT(varchar, ResolveDate, 101) then 1 else 0 end
          ) as TotalResolved

from cte
left join [WarehouseIncidents] T
ON CONVERT(varchar, CreateDate, 101) >= CONVERT(varchar, cte.date, 101)

GROUP BY CTE.DATE
```